# Группировка по двум полям и сумма в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Из базы данных мы получаем такой объект:

```
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Warehouses warehouses { get; set; }
    public Categories categories { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime receivingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? expirationDate { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double retailprice { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }    
}
```

Нужно сгруппировать данные по полям `name` и `dateOfReceiving` а также подсчитать сумму в значений в поле `price`

я пытался так:

```
Products = await _context.Products.Include(c => c.categories).ThenInclude(w => w.warehouses)
            .GroupBy(p => new { p.categories, p.warehouses, p.name, p.receivingDate, p.expirationDate, p.price, p.retailprice, p.description})
            .Select(x => new Products
            {
                categories = x.Key.categories,
                warehouses = x.Key.warehouses,
                name = x.Key.name,
                receivingDate = x.Key.receivingDate,
                expirationDate = x.Key.expirationDate, 
                price = x.Sum(y => y.price),
                retailprice = x.Key.retailprice,
                description = x.Key.description
            }).ToListAsync();
```

но получил ошибку

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression ... could not be translated

Comment: если вам нужно сгруппировать по `name` и `dateOfReceiving`, то почему вы, в таком случае, группируете по всем возможным полям?

Comment: также не совсем понимаю, что вы ожидаете в результате

Comment: без добавления в группировку они не появляются в select

Comment: появляются они в select или нет это уже совершенно другой момент, группировать то вам нужно по 2-м полям. И почему вы ожидаете в результате тип `Products`? Можно пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: должен получится список со всеми записями из таблицы сгруппированный по `name`' и `dateOfReceiving`, но без добавления остальных полей в GroupBy их нельзя добавить в `select` в конце

Comment: как сочетается одновременно "список записей" и "сгруппированные записи"? Повторюсь, пожалуйста, приведите пример записей и объекта, который вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: Если написать так: `var p = _context.Products.GroupBy(p => new { p.name, p.receivingDate}).Select(x => new Products{name = x.Key.name,receivingDate = x.Key.receivingDate,price = x.Sum(y => y.price),}).ToList();`
то все работает, но поля которых нет в группировке остаются пустыми.

Comment: вы так и не показали пример того, что есть и что хотите получить. Зачем вам все поля, если у вас группы? Можете описать задачу, которую вы решаете? Более глобально чем группировка по полям

Comment: есть таблица в бд, если значения в `name` и `receivingDate` у нескольких записей совпадают то они объединяются в одну и подсчитывается сумма в `price`

Comment: хорошо, вы говорите что они должны объединиться в одну запись. Вот скажем у первой записи `description ="description 1"`, а у второй - `description ="description 2"`. Что должно получится в результате по вашей логике в поле `description` после группировки?